# How to compare two objects in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I just wonder that how to compare two objects in a dictionary:

```
a = {}
while z:
    if a[z] == a[s]:
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("You don't know that country.")
    z = input("Enter a country: ")
    s = input("What is the capital of " + z + " ? ")
```

I want to print `Correct` when `z = s`; when `z` not in `a`, print `You don't know that country.`

Comment: ...what do you want to do with that dict?

Comment: This code makes no sense. Start over.

Comment: Which data is present in dictionary a?

Comment: You compare two objects in a dictionary the same way(s) you compare _any_ two objects.  That doesn't have much to do with your code or your stated goal, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `a` is a dictionary with the country as the key, and the capital as the value, you should make two separate checks: First you want to make sure that the entered country exists as a key in the dictionary. For that you should use the `in` operator. Second, you want to check whether the entered capital matches the capital in the dictionary. For that you perform an index access using the country on the dictionary and check whether the value equals the entered capital:

```
capitals = {
    'Austria': 'Vienna',
    'Belgium': 'Brussels',
    'Denmark': 'Copenhagen',
    'France': 'Paris',
    'Germany': 'Berlin',
    'Netherlands': 'Amsterdam',
    'Norway': 'Oslo',
    'Sweden': 'Stockholm',
    'Switzerland': 'Bern',
    'United Kingdom': 'London'
}

while True:
    country = input("Enter a country: ")

    # abort the loop if the user didn’t enter anything
    if not country:
        break

    # check whether we know that country
    if country in capitals:
        capital = input("What is the capital of {}? ".format(country))

        if capital == capitals[country]:
            print('That was correct!')
        else:
            print('You made a mistake there.')

    else:
        print('I do not know that country, sorry.')
```

Comment: a = {}
for i in open('capital-cities.txt'):
  part = i.split(",")
  country = part[0]
  capital = part[1]
  a[country] = capital
while True:
  country = input("Enter a country: ")
  if not country:
    break
  if country in a:
    capital = input("What is the capital of {}? ".format(country))
    if capital == part[0]:
      print('That was correct!')
    else:
      print('Sorry, it was ' + capital)
  else:
      print('I do not know that country, sorry.')

Comment: I try: Enter a country: Australia
What is the capital of Australia? Canberra
Sorry, it was Canberra

Comment: why it is {Australia:Canberra}, but shows "Sorry..."?

Comment: You are testing `if capital == part[0]` but you should test `if capital == a[country]`. Also, the error message should be `'Sorry, it was ' + a[country]`.

Answer (score -1):

I think the code you are looking for is the following. If not, please specify your question.

```
dict = {"Germany":"Berlin", "France":"Paris", "Italy":"Rome"}
while 1:
   country = input("Country: ")
   capital = input("Capital: ")
   if(dict[country] == capital):
       print("Correct!")
   else:
       print("Wrong!")
```

The input has to be in Quotes.